# How can I let my program run 100 times and save my results in a dataframe?

Tags: r, repeat

I have a program which divides my data in the first step into train and test set. After that,  a decision tree is built and I receive a confusion matrix.

**What I want to do** now is, repeat these steps ( divide train and test, decision tree and confusion matrix) for 100 times, so I always get a different train and test data set.

**What I want** is to get a resulting data frame with the accuracy, the sensitivity and the specifity of the confusion matrix.

The accuracy, sensitivity and the specifity are saved in vectors:

```
overall.accuracy <- format(overall['Accuracy'] * 100, nsmall =2, digits = 2)
overall.sensitivity <- format(cm$byClass['Sensitivity']* 100, nsmall =2, digits = 2)
overall.specificity <- format(cm$byClass['Specificity']* 100, nsmall =2, digits = 2)
```

My desired output would be sth like this:

```
> result_df

    accuracy      sensitivity    specifity 
1    30.22%          95.12%       30.23%
2    34.10%          80.12%       27.76%
3    31.56%          85.78%       28.98%
.       
.
.
100  32.33%          87.34%       29.45%
```

I could use `replicate()` but I am not familiar with this function and I don't know how to save the accuracy, sensitivity and the specificty of each cylce in a data frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would be to use a for loop, ie.

```
result_df<-matrix(ncol=3,nrow=100)
colnames(result_df)<-c("Acc","Sens","Spec")

for (i in 1:100)
{
YOUR CODE HERE
result_df[i,1] <- format(overall['Accuracy'] * 100, nsmall =2, digits = 2)
result_df[i,2] <- format(cm$byClass['Sensitivity']* 100, nsmall =2, digits = 2)
result_df[i,3] <- format(cm$byClass['Specificity']* 100, nsmall =2, digits = 2)
}
```

Comment: Hi Beavis! Thanks for your solution. I just tried to run it and it gave me this error message: `Error in `[<-`(`*tmp*`, 1, i, value = format(overall["Accuracy"] * 100,  : 
  subscript out of bounds` what does this mean?

Comment: Hi @hpmurg. Sorry, I hadn't checked my code properly. I put the rows and columns incorrectly in the result_df part. It should be correct now

Comment: It works, but the result_df has in every row and coulmn (except row 18) NA's...:/

Comment: That is likely an issue with your code then. If you run 'i=1', test it, and see what happens. Is it generating any warnings?

Comment: All my code is doing is taking the value you created and assigning it to the ith element in the 1st, 2nd, and 3rd column, so it won't produce any NA's that aren't already there. To test this you could try `result_df<-matrix(rep("-",300),ncol=3,nrow=100)` to start off with, and then when the loop is finished if a cell has NA it's your code producing them, and any -s mean it isn't producing anything

Comment: I used your suggestion, and it gives me `"-"` in every row and column, except for row 18 again

Comment: Ok. Without the rest of your code I can't really help you any further. The fact that only 1 of your values is working is odd but it means my answer is still correct, and so it's likely that it's going wrong earlier in the code. If you look into for loops you might be able to find the answer, but with no detail on what the rest of you code is doing I can't debug it

Comment: I could solve it, just change `i` into a different, not used parameter e.g. `m`.